# Iterating through circle elements in d3

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way I could iterate through all circle elements that I added to a graph? For example, let's say I created four circles on a graph with specific id values. If I want to find a circle element with a specific id, how should I got about doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You would do something like

```
svg.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d) { return d.id == myid; });
```

assuming that you have bound data to the circles that contains an `.id` attribute.